# Google firebase retrieve analytics data through the API

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-analytics

I had search for an API which provides access to firbase.
I got python-firebase api which only interacts with database of firebase.
Is there any way from where, we can get aggregate data listed on the analytics dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use python-firebase to access analytics data since there is no REST API for Firebase Analytics.

In order to work with the data you have to link your Firebase project to BigQuery. https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-big-query